# Clear screen in C and C++ on UNIX-based system?

Tags: c, unix, screen, cls

I want to know: how to clean screen on an UNIX-based system? I searched on the Internet, but I've just found how to do it on Windows: system("CLS")
I don't want exactly to clean cpmpletely the screen, but I want to open a "new page", such as in the NANO and VI editors. Thanks

Comment: vi and nano use buffers to keep the text-data. You would Need to implement such a buffer and a Scrolling mechanism.

Comment: `printf("\e[2J\e[H");`

Answer (score 24):

Maybe you can make use of escape codes

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define clear() printf("\033[H\033[J")

int main(void)
{
    clear();
    return 0;
}
```

But keep in mind that this method is not compatible with all terminals

Comment: Can you elaborate "\033[H\033[J"

Comment: [ANSI/VT100 Terminal Control Escape Sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm)

Comment: @DavidRanieri link is dead :(

Comment: https://www.ecse.rpi.edu/courses/CStudio/Old%20MPS%20Labs/MPS_ANSI_Lab_Ex2.pdf

This URL says that `\033[H` will position the cursor to the home position and `\033[J` stands for erase lines below. `\033[2J` erases the screen & moves cursor to the home position so you might only need this.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the following code which use termcap for clear screen.
(don't forget to link with the library)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termcap.h>

void clear_screen()
{
char buf[1024];
char *str;

tgetent(buf, getenv("TERM"));
str = tgetstr("cl", NULL);
fputs(str, stdout);
}
```

Comment: +1, on Debian you have to install `libncurses5-dev` and compile using `-lncurses`

Answer (score 6):

Portable UNIX code should be using the terminfo database for all cursor and screen manipulation. This is what libraries like `curses` uses to achieve its effects like windowing and so forth.

The terminfo database maintains a list of capabailities (like `clear` which is what you would use to clear the screen and send the cursor to the top). It maintains such capabilities for a *wide* range of devices so that you don't have to worry about whether you're using a Linux console or a (very dated) VT52 terminal.

As to how you *get* the character streams for certain operations, you can choose the time-honored but rather horrible method of just using `system` to do it:

```
system ("tput clear");
```

Or you can capture the output of that command to a buffer so later use involve only outputting the characters rather than re-running the command:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static char scrTxtCls[20]; static size_t scrSzCls;

// Do this once.

FILE *fp = popen ("tput clear", "r");
scrSzCls = fread (scrTxtCls, 1, sizeof(scrTxtCls), fp);
pclose (fp);
if (scrSzCls == sizeof(scrTxtCls)) {
    actIntelligently ("you may want to increase buffer size");
}

// Do this whenever you want to clear the screen.

write (1, cls, clssz);
```

Or, you can link with `ncurses` and use its API to get whatever capabilities you want, though this might drag in quite a bit of stuff for something as simple as clearing the screen. Still, it's an option to be considered seriously since it gives you a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    system("clear");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is usually not a matter of just clearing the screen, but of making a terminal aware application.

You should use the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library and read the [NCURSES programming HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

<sup>(You could perhaps use some [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) as [David RF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17271636/841108) answered, but I don't think it is a good idea)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using CSI sequences:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("\x1b[H\x1b[J");
}
```

#### What does `\x1b[H`?

Actually it is the same as `\x1b[1;1;H`, it means that it will move the cursor to row 1 and column 1.

#### What does `\x1b[J` a.k.a `\x1b[0;J`?

If n is 0 or missing, it will clear from cursor to end of screen.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences

Comment: Wouldn't `\x1b[2J` be enough for moving cursor and clearing the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `#include<stdlib.h>` after `#include<stdio.h>`.

Then you can use the command `system("clear");`after `main() {`

i.e:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("clear");
```

After these commands you can continue with your program.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

To clear the screen using termcaps, use this :

```
write(1, tgetstr("cl", 0), strlen(tgetstr("cl", 0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `system("clear");` with header `#include <stdlib.h>` (for C Language) or `#include <cstdlib>` (for C++).

Comment: This is the one you should try.

Comment: This has the disadvantage of starting a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

**This code is for clear  screen with reset scrollbar position  in terminal style windows**

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   std::cout << "\033c";
   return 0;
}
```