# how to clear my previous output in Linux terminal using C?

Tags: c

This is my sample program for simulating a Loading progress. The only problem I'm facing right now is clearing my previous output of "Loading: %i"

```
/* loading program */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TIMELIMIT 5

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0, j; i < 5; ++i) {
        j = i;
        printf("Loading: %i%%", ++j);
        sleep(1);
    //system("bash -c clear");    not working
    //printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H"); clears whole screen with no output at all
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: i think this should just be `printf("\033[2J");` and remove the system

Comment: tried that again. Same as comment 2

Comment: Can you try `system("./clear");`?

Comment: ./clear not found. Outputs 5 times

Comment: If it still doesn't work, insert a few `\n`s :)

Comment: you mean system("./clear\n's"); ??

Comment: No, I meant a bunch of `printf("\n");` in your C program. It will give you a feeling of `clear`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear screen in C and C++ on UNIX-based system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271576/clear-screen-in-c-and-c-on-unix-based-system)

Comment: that's the output I didn't intend to have... I needed output more like clrscr() on turbo C

Comment: Try adding `fflush(stdout);` after each of the `printf()`s.  Output is likely being buffered until `printf()` sees a newline or the stream gets explicitly flushed.

Comment: YAY!!! works out now!!! Thanks Dmitri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway here is the correct code. Thanks to Mobius and Dmitri.

```
/* loading program */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TIMELIMIT 5

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0, j; i < TIMELIMIT; ++i) {
        j = i;
        printf("Loading: %i%%", ++j);
        printf("\r");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you print `\r` instead of `\n` using `printf`, then it will return to the beginning of the same line instead of the next line. Then you can re-print the new status on top of the old line.

Comment: @Seek Addo
tried it this way printf("Loading: %i%%\r", ++j);
shows me the last output but blanks out the rest/no output at all
Same with bunch of printf("\n"); and printf("\r");

Comment: sorry for some reason i did not realize you were in `C`. But I see you found that you have to call `fflush(stdout)`, so all is well

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question is system("reset").
This is the command you're looking for

```
    reset
```

this command clears your whole terminal.

and your code go like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TIMELIMIT 5

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    for(int i = 0, j; i < 5; ++i) {
        j = i;
        system("reset");
        printf("Loading: %i%%\n", ++j);
        sleep(1);
    //system("bash -c clear");    not working
    //printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H"); clears whole screen with no output at all
    }
    return(0);
}
```