# How can i clearscreen in a while loop, in C programming?

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include <studio.h>

int main()
{
   int num;
  
    while(1)
        printf("Enter the number");

    scanf("%d",num);

    printf("Your number is %d", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have indented your code, as you can see the `while` loop only affects the `printf` line, you also have a typo: `studio.h` should be `stdio.h`. Regarding your question, take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/q/17271576/1606345

Comment: You might want to add braces to that while loop. As is, it doesn't look like useful behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).